# What is darkness?

Tags: metaphysics

What does dark truly mean if suppose we never knew or witnessed there is something called light but we have always associated darkness with absence of light but what if we don't know what it is, would it be nothing then what Nothing means without knowing what is light and dark

Comment: So you're thinking of a society trapped in darkness having audio logs of their ancestors describing darkness to them as the absence of light. Never having experienced anything but darkness (but not by it's name) and having no concept of what light is? Well it depends on how familiar they are with the concepts. Like how do they know it, what do they associate with these words or is it just HFHDEQK which is the opposite of FHDJFH but you haven't heard either of these 2 words?

Comment: I can't see or feel radio waves. But they are there. They were there before we knew they existed. So, for radio waves, we were blind, but it was not dark.

Comment: IDK but it's scary.

Comment: I mean, interesting idea maybe, but I see no need for these kind of divisions, thanks

Comment: Darkness is merely a perception of our visual apparatus linked to very few or no photons of the right wavelength and number being able to excite the nerves in our retina. For cats, what we perceive as dark can be pretty well lit. The link to nothingness is pretty arbitrary as well. Therefore, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Indeed if one never sees light such as a blind man one's darkness could not be properly said to be associated with absence of light. But one thing is still the same with ordinary persons which is that the said blind man still *sees* nothing but darkness and in the meanwhile he still could conceive its negation which is nothing but the wonderful (conceptual) categorical understanding of the same quality of "light" as compared to ordinary persons if he can somehow fill up his time so fully with a metaphoric "sensation" that light could be said to be real for him not unlike the freed caved man...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because bad poetry is not philosophy.

Comment: Book: Shadows: Unlocking Their Secrets, from Plato to Our Time by Roberto Casati
Roberto Casati
Shadows: Unlocking Their Secrets, from Plato to Our